# Google Maps and GMapCatcher... File/Directory Naming System

Tags: google-maps

Does anyone have any ideas as to how GMapCatcher knows which folders/directories to store the tiles as?  I know it is some combination of x,y, and zoom levels, but I really don't see how they are determining which folders the tiles get stored in, and was wandering if anyone had any insight as to how they determine what tiles to retrieve?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scrapbook/googlemap.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I just found the answer after some searching.

A tile that is stored in:

C:\Users\Dog\.googlemaps\tiles\-1\74\541\96\982.png

will have coordinates:

x = 74*1024 + 541, y = 96*1024 + 982, zoom = -1

I'm not sure yet how the tile coordinates correspond to latitude/longitude at the different zoom levels, though.  It would be nice if GMapCatcher would tell me which tile I'm looking at with a right-click menu option or something.

Comment: Were you ever able to determine how to re-stitch tiles together and associate them to lat/lng?

Answer (score 0):

In the settings window of GMapCatcher where you specify the Custom Maps Directory, a dropdown gives you the choices of the storage format.  I like OSM, Open Street Map format.  You can read about the storage method here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames